# dates to string parsing

Tags: java, parsing, gregorian-calendar

Given a text file here:

```
       Date    Opening    Closing
 6-Mar-2012   500         1000
 9-Jun-2011   110         970
 7-Dec-2015   1090        980.69
28-Feb-2010   500         800
```

I need to build the dates in GregorianCalendar and have the date constructors in String. The date is shown Null in my output, any idea on a fix?

Output:

```
The date is null, the opening is 500, and the closing is 800
```

The date is declared GregorianCalendar, however, The constructors are taking date in String, and should expect the form "dd-MM-yyyy".

Class Djia:

```
public class Djia implements Comparable<Djia> {
    // instance variables
    private GregorianCalendar date; 
    private double opening;
    private double closing; 

    public Djia(String dt, double opening, double closing) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat stringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = stringDate.parse(dt);
        Calendar gCal = new GregorianCalendar();
        gCal.setTime(date);
        this.opening = opening;
        this.closing = closing;
    }

    public String date() {
        String date;
        SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        date = dateformat.format(this.date.getTime());
        return date;
    }

    public double opening() {
        return opening;
    }

    public double closing() {
        return closing;
    }

    //...
}
```

Main Method:
I have done parsing and formatting here, because months are of String representation in the given text file. First, I parsed months to Integer representation and then formatted from Date to String because Djia Class only take Date as String.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] fields = line.split(" ");
    String date = fields[0];
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy");
    Date nDate = simpleDate.parse(date);
    Format stringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String newDate = stringDate.format(nDate); 
    double closing = Double.parseDouble(fields[2]);
    double opening = Double.parseDouble(fields[1]);
    Djia newDjia = new Djia(newDate, opening, closing);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the date format ? On the API, I see a lot of YYYY-MM-DD but not DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a short but *complete* program rather than snippets. (It doesn't help that you've got 4 different formats in your code, with no indication why.) However: a) you don't want to use YYYY when formatting; b) you should use `d-MMM-yyyy` when parsing, given that you don't always have two digits. c) `dd-mm-yyyy` should be `dd-MM-yyyy` as `mm` means minutes, not months. See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/ for more advice.

Comment: Use Java 8 or JodaTime and save yourself from an unnecessary trip to an institution.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon, our professor said to do it this way(4 different formats) we have no choice.. and she's not very good at teaching to be honest..

Comment: Well you certainly haven't explained what you're trying to achieve. *Why* would you use 4 date formats? How is your final string constructed from a `Djia`? While your professor may not be good at teaching, that doesn't stop you from explaining your problem clearly. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry edited the date formats. date is declared GregorianCalendar in Class Djia, the constructors and final output should expect String form "dd-MM-yyyy".

Comment: This still isn't a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. We still don't know what's building your final string, or what debugging steps you've taken, or *why* you're parsing and formatting multiple times (other than via a vague description in a comment).

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you please take another look, I have edited my question.

Comment: Still no short but complete program, still no explanation of *why* `Djia` accepts a `String` rather than a `Date` or `Caledar`, still no indication of how the final line is produced. Did you read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints as I suggested?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I have :) The professor made Djia only to accept String.The program is long, I didn't want to post it all here. I have wrote an insert method to add the lines of text in a LinkedList and prints out the output.

Comment: @Katherine: Where does it say that in the question? People reading your question should *not* have to read through a long comment thread in order to understand it. If you've read through my suggestions, I'm unclear why your question *still* doesn't include a short but complete program or all the details I've asked about. Note that it doesn't need to be your full program - it just needs to be a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Well, your date `private GregorianCalendar date;` is still `null`, because you don't initialize is somewhere. You create some local variables called `date`, but this has nothing to do with your instance field `date`.

Comment: @Katherine I answered you 10 minutes ago with a solution

Comment: @Xithias thanks a lot! Is it possible to use LinkedList implementation instead of ArrayList?

Comment: @Katherine yes, there's no change in the results

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have space characters at the beginnig of the line:

try changing the line:

`String[] fields=line.split(" ");`

to

`String[] fields=line.trim().split(" ");`

by adding the trim() call, that will remove any space charcters form the beginning and the end of your line.

or do:

```
 String dateString = line.substring(0, 12);
```

if there is always the same length and align of the date part of the line.

Comment: Still outputs Null :)

Answer (score 1):

You´ve got to do this in your main:

- Set your Locale in the SimpleDateFormat
- Make a list (not an array) with the split, and delete the empty
  elements

Here is the result:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Djia {

    private GregorianCalendar date;
    private double opening;
    private double closing;

    public Djia(String dt, double opening, double closing)
            throws ParseException {

        DateFormat stringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        Date date = stringDate.parse(dt);
        GregorianCalendar gCal = new GregorianCalendar();
        gCal.setTime(date);

        this.opening = opening;
        this.closing = closing;
        this.date = gCal;
    }

    public String date() {
        String date;
        SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
        date = dateformat.format(this.date.getTime());
        return date;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                LinkedList fields=new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.trim().split(" ")));
                for (int i=fields.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    if (fields.get(i).equals("")) {
                        fields.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                String date = (String) fields.get(0);
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
                Date nDate = simpleDate.parse(date);
                Format stringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
                String newDate = stringDate.format(nDate);
                double closing = Double.parseDouble((String) fields.get(2));
                double opening = Double.parseDouble((String) fields.get(1));
                Djia newDjia = new Djia(newDate, opening, closing);
                System.out.println("The date is " + newDate + ", the opening is " + opening + ", and the closing is " + closing);

            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't need a raw type `ArrayList` if you would use a correct delimiter to split on.

Comment: And where does it fix the problem in the `Djia` class?

Comment: @Tom i didn't change anything in the Djia class that Katherine posted. The code works, I tried it.

Comment: @Tom Yea, I tested it again, this doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @Tom How to initialize GregorianCalendar date when Public Djia only takes String date?

Comment: @Katherine Well, you're using `this.opening = opening;` to intialize the `opening` field. So  you need something similar for the `date` field. And you need an instance of `GregorianCalender`, which you already have in your constructor. You only need to use that to initialize your `this.date` ;).

Comment: @Xithias The code works for you? You ignoriere the results of the `Dija` constructor and the values of the instance fields. No wonder you didn't notice the uninitialized `date` field.

Comment: @Tom now I understand. I was only focused in showing the results in the main. I edited the answer with the init of the calendar. :)

Comment: @Katherine I edited already my answer, you have it all there :)

Comment: @Xithias the output is The date is java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1142506800000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=s..........  :)

Comment: @Katherine  That is the default output if you print a `GregorianCalendar` to the console (by calling `toString` on it). If you want the current date and time of your instance, then try `gCal.getTime()` (or `this.date.getTime()`). This returns a `java.util.Date` which has a formatted `toString` implementation.

Comment: @Tom sorry this is all very confusing to me, I think I'll start another question :) thank u very much Tom